# learning nhibernate (with or without fluent)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am going to try using NHibernate, the reason I stayed away from NHibernate so far was the xml-mapping part. Now that (I found out) there is fluent nhibernate, looks like we don't need to do xml mapping.

But I am wondering if starting with some xml mapping, would be more helpful in learning and getting comfortable with NHibernate, or should I start using it with fluent for nhibernate?

cheers,
hazim

Comment: this might also be worth reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350907/nhibernate-or-fluent-nhibernate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had similar concerns when I started with nHibernate, but having taken the road of learning the mappings and then learning Fluent, I have to say I wish I had just started with Fluent.

My reasoning is that there was enough to digest just learning nHibernate and Fluent helps make nHibernate more simple.  Having said that I agree with David M, you'll need to understand the mappings at some point.

This [series](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) was really useful when I was learning nHibernate.

HTH

Answer (score 4):

I would actually recommend attacking NHib from a totally Fluent perspective right now - FNH has matured just enough to not drive you nuts with inconsistencies, there are a lot of decent learning aids out there (try and look at anything posted since Sep 2009 on at first), as well as a decently active [user group](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate?hl=en).

I found this amazingly good and very recent video tutorial [Vacation of Fluent NHibernate](http://vimeo.com/user2515896), conceptually based on the Summer of NHib series everyone else has here. Unfortunately the author just got a new job and hasn't yet completed the series, but I will be shocked if you don't find it incredibly approachable and useful as a learning tool all the same.

You also can fairly easily learn to generate the HBM maps, and reading them is way more useful IMO, and certainly less painful, than writing them at first.

Lastly, give yourself a break and don't expect to master any of this by the end of the week! If you spend some time with FNH first, you will know which areas of NHib you want to dig into eventually and feel less overwhelmed by it when you do.

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you get started with a simple database schema using Fluent's auto mapping, so you can get used to using NHibernate Sessions and SessionFactories properly. Then you can branch out. But at some point you will need to fall back on XML mapping, so it's worth looking at eventually.

Answer (score 1):

For understanding what is going I'd recommend starting with XML Mapping files. When learning NHibernate I found hand building configuration files to be useful. That said after I was comfortable using fluent and the occasional mapping file builder has been great.

For learning NHibernate though it's targeted at a previous version the [Summer of NHibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) is incredibly useful.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the XML mappings. Fluent is getting closer to being feature complete, but the terminology it uses still diverges from the terminology within the XML mappings (which is what is used by most NHibernate tutorials / documentation).  Once you've done a mapping or two, it really isn't that hard especially with intellisense support from the schema files.

Fluent NHibernate is great, but for a beginner I think it might lead to some confusion as you cross reference your mappings with online research.