# What versions of firebird are supported by nHibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, firebird

I would like to use fluent-nHibernate for different databases of firebird with different versions. I found some information on the jboss website but nothing at http://nhibernate.info/

Which versions are supported and where do i find things like this?

Comment: The 2.5.x versions all work for us. We tried an older version (one of the 2.0.x), where the schema creation failed. But I don't know where to get any official information about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since fluent-nHibernate sits on top of nHibernate you only need this one to support Firebird. If you check the [source](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Cfg/Db/FirebirdConfiguration.cs) for the fluent-nHibernate Firebird configuration you will see there is no reference to any Firebird version.

Said this, according to this [link](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DatabasesSupportedByNHibernate) at jBoss, `Firebird is supported since version 1.5.3, though version 2.1 is strongly recommended` in nHibernate. The same link gives also advice on how to configure your application.

This link also says you should always try to use the latest Firebird .NET provider, which you can download from [Firebird's webpage](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/).

Finally, you can find more information on the difference between nHibernate and fluent-nHibernate can be found in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350907/nhibernate-or-fluent-nhibernate).